# How can a function be added as a key-value pair in an object?

Tags: javascript, function, javascript-objects

I am working on the following code, and some sort of error is being found on the adding of 3 key-value pairs in the myData object:

```
var myArray = ["Francisco Souza Homem de Mello","franciscomello"];

var namer = myArray[0];

function cutName(namer) {

  return namer.split(" ");
}

var boxy = cutName(namer);

var myData = {
  fullname: cutName(namer),
  skype: myArray[1],
  github: "franciscomello"
};
```

The error is probaly on calling the cutName function on the myData object, but I cannot seem to find how to call it.

Comment: `fullname: function () { cutName(namer) }`

Comment: What do you mean by "some sort of error"? What happens, and what were you expecting?

Comment: The page is not accepting my code. The instructions are fullName: call cutName on the name string stored in the array!!!

Comment: Do you know the javascript console? it displays error information when you made errors.

Comment: If you want to store the function `cutName` in the "global" Function, you can make the object.key = value a `this`-hereditary-, fat-arrow `myData["fullname"] = () => cutName(namer)`

Answer (score 2):

fullname: cutName(namer) is not correct. you are expecting fullname to be a function but cutName(namer) is the return value of cutName() with param namer. 
           `fullname: cutName` or 
                    `fullname: function () { cutName(namer) }` should work.

Comment: Not really... it still is not solved. It says in the instruction ":fullName : call cutName on the name string stored in the array"

Comment: Really need help here